# Write an array of bytes to EEPROM from PROGMEM

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to store an array of LED patterns to EEPROM, to later write to an external flash module. Below is my header file containing the patterns.

```cpp
#ifndef DefaultPatterns_h
#define DefaultPatterns_h

#define DEFAULT_SIZE 147
const byte defaultData[DEFAULT_SIZE] PROGMEM ={225,112,111,};

#define RAINBOWPIXEL_SIZE 972
const byte rainbowpixelData[RAINBOWPIXEL_SIZE] PROGMEM ={255,0,0,0,0,0,0}; 
#endif
```

I've cut some bytes out from the above patterns as they are too long for this post.

Below is my sketch that is taken from ESP8266 EEPROM example library and I'm trying to use it as a starting point. I've commented out some things I've tried. Remember the patterns are in a header file.

```cpp
#include "EEPROM.h"
#include "defaultPatterns.h"

int addr = 0;// address of EEPROM to write to

void setup() {
  EEPROM.begin(512);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  //const byte defaultData[] = PROGMEM(defaultData,DEFAULT_SIZE );
  // write the value to the appropriate byte of the EEPROM.
  // these values will remain there when the board is
  // turned off.
  // EEPROM.write(addr, val);
  //EEPROM.write(addr,byte (defaultData)) sizeof(defaultData));
  //EEPROM.write ( 0, (byte *)defaultData), sizeof(defaultData)));

  const char pattern = defaultData ;

  EEPROM.write(addr, pattern);
  // advance to the next address. There are 512 bytes in
  // the EEPROM, so go back to 0 when we hit 512.
  // save all changes to the flash.
  addr = addr + 1;
  if (addr == 512) {
    addr = 0;
    EEPROM.commit();
  }
  delay(100);
}
```

I've tried all sorts of different ways, but I'm getting errors and syntax errors.

I've tried to do this myself but I'll be at it forever. Any help that would be great.

I'm trying to build a LED controller that can store lots of patterns in the form of the patterns in the header file and play them back via a WS2812B strip of LEDs on button press. I've a long way to go.

Why use flash you ask? Space, I need lots of space. I know flash wears out faster, but I can replace it for a few bucks.

Comment: Also asked at http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=507293

Comment: I'm getting errors and syntax errors. isn't very helpful...

Answer (score 0):

Look at the definition of `EEPROM.write()` - it only writes one byte.  You need to use a `for` loop or `EEPROM.put()`.

Comment: Ok thanks i forgot about the EEPROM.put() it writes any data type does`t it?

Comment: The documentation says "primitive type or custom struct".